# Add a newline after every write to ByteArrayOutputStream/PrintStream

Tags: java

I have a web application that sends a response to the client with console information from the Java backend. In order to do this, I've changed System.out/System.err's streams like so:

```
ByteArrayOutputStream baos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
PrintStream ps = new PrintStream(baos);
PrintStream old = System.out;
System.setOut(ps);
```

However, there are no newlines between each write to the ByteArrayOutputStream/PrintStream. I want the same breaks I'd see if System.out.println was printing to Terminal instead of the PrintStream I created. Any ideas how to do this?

Comment: I don't see anything wrong with this code. How does the write code look like? What does the output look like?

Comment: Can you show how you are calling this? and what the output is?

Comment: are you checking your output file in windows notepad?

Comment: Thanks to @NayukiMinase - I checked the response containing the System.out content via my JavaScript front-end and noticed that there were newlines, but it wasn't rendering them due to being placed into HTML. Simply replacing all newlines with `<br>` made the response render as I intended.

Comment: Sounds good. Since you're rendering to HTML, there are alternative to the `<br>` solution. You can also use CSS `style="white-space:pre"` or simply `<pre>`.